# sql server removing service_queues

Tags: sql-server, service-broker, installation

When I query `select * from sys.service_queues` in SQL Server 2008 sp3, I  am getting:

```
InternalMailQueue
ExternalMailQueue
_LakeSide_DbTools_DeadlockQueue
QueryNotificationErrorsQueue
EventNotificationErrorsQueue
_LakeSide_DbTools_LockQueue
syspolicy_event_queue
ServiceBrokerQueue
```

I need to remove `_LakeSide_DbTools_DeadlockQueue` and `_LakeSide_DbTools_LockQueue` from MSDB database permanently. I installed that lakesidetool and manually removed all procedures, now stuck in removing this services. I used their uninstall tool, but it didn't help.
http://www.sqlsolutions.com/products/sql-deadlock-detector/Uninstall.html

Answer (score 3):

Queues are schema bound objects and as such they may belong to a different schema than your current default schema (likely `dbo`). If that's the case the DROP statement must qualify the queue with a two part name:

```
DROP QUEUE <schema>.<queue>;
```

You can get the schema name from sys.service_queues:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id), name FROM sys.service_queues;
```

Answer (score 2):

If no services refer to the queue, you could simply run a `DROP QUEUE` statement:

```
drop queue _LakeSide_DbTools_DeadlockQueue;
go

drop queue _LakeSide_DbTools_LockQueue;
go
```

[BOL reference on DROP QUEUE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190480.aspx)

Comment: No  i tried it  gives the error, Cannot drop the queue '_LakeSide_DbTools_LockQueue', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: How can i drop queue if any services refer to the queue.